# Any way to dismiss "Say hello to your new Chrome browser" in 69?

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

After upgrading to 69.0.3497.92, this dialog pops up in the top-right corner for *every* new tab page (`chrome://newtab`). It's just annoying and I want to dismiss it. Theme is irrelevant, it happens with the default theme.

Comment: I cannot replicate it, but just a thought. Have you gone through the show me what's new at all? Maybe if you go through it, it will stop popping up.

Comment: @Jimmy_A Yes. I tried both options multiple times.

Comment: Have you tried going through 'what's new' right to the end?

Comment: @Tetsujin [Nope.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ7w0.png)

Comment: You potentially have a registry/write-rights issue, so Chrome can't save that you answered. I had the pop-up one time on each machine, and after chosing 'no thanks', it never came again.

Comment: I selected "Show me what's new".  Clicked on the down arrow on first screen.  Scrolled to end.  Already signed out so couldn't do that as per @keijak.

Comment: @XavierBourretSicotte This is my question. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @XavierBourretSicotte It's absolutely normal that a solution doesn't apply to everyone, while another one applies to those to whom the first one fails.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and successfully dismissed the annoying dialog by doing sign-out from the profile icon at the top right corner of the newtab page (not the top bar of Chrome) and sign-in again.

Comment: How did you sign out from the new tab page? Did you sign out of Chrome?

Comment: Click your profile icon. I think I signed out of Google rather than of Chrome. Visiting google.com and signing out there (instead of chrome://newtab) might have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Close Chrome, open `Preferences` JSON file in profile directory (usually `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\`),
Remove this key-value pair `"last_known_google_url":"xxxxx"`, save it.

Comment: +1 This has solved it for me on El Capitan

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Chrome and log in to your Google account
2. Go to settings
3. Go to cookies
4. Allow chrome to set cookies
5. Preserve cookies to be stored locally after closing Chrome
6. Dis-allow third party cookies
7. Close Chrome
8. Restart computer

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is to allow Google to set cookies.  In the address bar, almost all of the way to the right, you should see what I think they mean to be a cookie with a red box with a white x in it. Allow the cookies.

Comment: Can't see this cookie box on chrome for the mac unfortunately. This constant message is very annoying.

Comment: Reducing your privacy is not "the correct answer" to a software defect.